# Materialize datepicker - Rendering when an icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, material-design

I'm trying to use google's materialize date picker (http://materializecss.com/forms.html). In their examples they have used it with `<input>` elements like [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnhjh6pu/4/).

HTML: `<input class="datepicker" value="click"></input>`

JQuery:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
});
```

---

But I want to do it with `<i>` elements like [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnhjh6pu/5/) which is not working properly. The problem is I have to click and hold the mouse to see the date picker here..!

HTML: `<i class="datepicker">click</i>`

JQuery:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
});
```

Anybody knows a solution for making this to work properly when I click (*without disappearing after releasing the mouse*)?

Comment: Why do you want to use an `<i>` tag?

Comment: to create a icon (http://materializecss.com/icons.html). I just want to popup the datepicker when the user clicks on the icon. @brso05

Comment: Try hiding the input element and triggering the `click` event of the input when the icon is clicked...

Comment: @brso05 thanks. I tried it. But it didn't work and raised another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832007/strange-behaviour-in-material-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a event listener to your icon and then use the method .open().

```
  var element = document.querySelector('.datepicker');  
  $('.datepicker-icon').on('click', function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          M.Datepicker.getInstance(element).open();
      });
```

The Stop propagation is not my idea tho, i read it [here](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/481)