# Strange behaviour in Material datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, material-design

I'm trying to use materialize date picker (http://materializecss.com/forms.html). With that, I want to popup the date picker when I click on an icon. I have implemented two implementations where the only difference between the two is putting an `alert('clicked')` with the code.

**without the `alert('clicked')`**: http://jsfiddle.net/1bnnkhbw/

**with the `alert('clicked')`**: http://jsfiddle.net/1bnnkhbw/1/

*The second one works while the first one doesn't.. (in chrome)!!!*

Anybody knows the reason for this behavior?

And a way to make the 1st one work?

Comment: For me it worked when I used the inspect element mode (in chrome) for that tab. Seems to be a problem with focusing (not sure)..

Comment: Oops the first fiddle didn't work I just update the answer with working fiddle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found a solution for you man check this out:

```
<i id="icon">click</i>
<input class="datepicker" style="display:none;" value="click"></input>



$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true,
    selectYears: 15 
  });

$('#icon').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".datepicker").first().pickadate("picker").open();
    console.log("test1");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2qtzp7p/1/

Code taken from [here](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/481) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J92K6/)